# How to set the Extended Power Condition (EPC) timers of a hard-drive

Tags: hard-drive, sata, power-management

I have a Ultrastar DC HC550 SATA disk that supports different idle and standby states (idle_a, idle_b, idle_c etc).
They are described in the [product manual](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/ultrastar-dc-hc500-series/product-manual-ultrastar-dc-hc550-sata-oem-spec.pdf)
along with the timers listed in chapter 10.19.3.

How do I set all the power management configuration? I would like to enter idle_c (low RPM) after a short time and spin down with a much higher timeout.

The disk will be used on Windows but I can connect it using a SATA-USB-bridge to a linux box for setup if needed (given the settings are persistent).

Answer (score 0):

Use camcontrol of FreeBSD. Build yourself a live USB stick by e.g. using a NomadBSD image.

Show device ids:
camcontrol devlist

Set EPC timer:
camcontrol epc DEVICE_ID -c timer -p idle_c -T TIME_IN_SECONDS -e  -s

More information about other EPC timers and the APM feature here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1047331/how-do-i-disable-hard-disk-spin-down-or-head-parking-in-freebsd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135228)

Comment: I'm the author of the linked answer. I can tell you setting it in another system and rebooting to Linux *won't work*. The Extended Power Condition (EPC) settings are not persistent, unless it's explicitly saved via a command (which was *not* described in that answer). Thus, they must be set on every boot. According to the *ATA/ACS-2 specification 4.8.2 Power conditions*: *default and saved settings shall persist across power cycles. The current settings shall not persist across power cycles.* The fact that Linux lacks a standard tool an industry-standard power management feature is worrying.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new subsection on saving EPC settings permanently, thus, if the new instructions are followed, it's now possible to program EPC settings on FreeBSD for their later use on Linux. I also noticed thattThere exists a 3rd-party EPC tool for Linux on GitHub called wdepc (github.com/tyan-boot/wdepc), which was "motivated" by my description of its use o FreeBSD. You can give it a try.